# How to achieve realistic snow roll over?

Tags: physics, dynamic-paint

I was trying to create a snow simulation(where a ball of snow rolled through a snow field displaces the snow and the snow ball gains weight/volume as it moves along i.e gets bigger in size).So,I added a plane,subdivided it numerous times to get fine vertex,and used dynamic paint with displace property.But,the problem is that the ball(brush) was able to displace the mesh but it didn't increased in size as I wanted.So if any of you guys have any idea,please suggest.Thanks.Here's an example of what I would like to do.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9FTax-mxZc

Comment: Have you tried to add keyframes for the scale?

Comment: That's probably done with [molecular addon](http://pyroevil.com/molecular-script-download/)

Comment: @ lemon,ok adding keyframe would make the ball bigger,but I want the ball to be taking its share from the snow in the ground as it gets bigger.@p2or-hey man do you have any idea how to get on with using molecular addon or at least can you direct me towards some good tutorials.

Comment: @p2or While you probably *could* use the molecular add-on for this, the author states in the comments that they didn't use it.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker Here is one and only by the time good tutorial on Molecular Addon (https://youtu.be/haS3B6q82kY), and here is snow sim created in it: https://youtu.be/55_plFGIPGY. You will want to use CubeSurfer with it to make solid mesh from particles. You can make ball bigger based on roll trough displace/dynamic paint. There is none physical information taken from it. Only way is as lemon said, do it manually.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker If you'll have further issues with Molecular, edit this question accordingly and notify me here in comments, I'll try to help.